# 15 noded triangular elements in paraview

Tags: visualization, paraview, vtk

I am modelling a soil medium in plane strain and would like to determine if paraview supports the 15-noded triangular element as shown on [this](https://dianafea.com/manuals/d944/ElmLib/node149.html) link.

On the documentation I am only seeing elements up to second order for an unstructured grid (please see [VTK users guide](http://www.vtk.org/vtk-users-guide/) pages 480 and 481. I also found some indication on this link that other element types might be supported, but nothing specifically regarding the element type I am after.

Furthermore the model I am using has additional stress points (9 of them) in addition to the geometric nodes on the model. I am not terribly worried about these for the time being although I will eventually have to include them in the rendition.

Comment: Regarding your stresses at Gauss points (I suppose) you can use Field Data. Regarding the higher order elements, you can the [VTK source code for cells](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/vtkCellType_8h_source.html). It seems that they have higher order triangles ... but they might not be available in Paraview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately (unless things have changed very recently) VTK doesn't fully support anything higher than second order cells in terms of mesh visualisation and filtering. Various common workarounds based on upscaling have been attempted, see for example [this related question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7468/fenics-visualizing-high-order-elements).